# Fire a specific alert once in 7 days interval - Alertmanger

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We have 300 VMs grouped in 20 groups by label, project name (x, y, ...). There are 35 alerts for the VMs as follows:

```
- alert: LowDiskSpace
- alert: LowMemory
- alert: HighCpuLoad
......
```

Alerts are being forwarded to 20 Slack channels based on the label, project name. If an alert is fired from a specific VM, the Prometheus query output contains the label which was assigned for that particular VM. Then the alert forwarded to different Slack channel matching the label. I want to fire `HighCpuLoad` once in every 7 days. That means, it should check for alert in day 1, if active then fire only once then check again after 6 days. It must be done in Prometheus side. It can be done in Alertmanager side by matching an extra label for all 20 channels which will hamper forwarding other alerts. My Alertmanager route configs as follows:

```
route:
  receiver: 'common_channel'
  repeat_interval: 10m

  routes:
  - receiver: 'receiver_1'
    matchers:
      - project_name = "x"
    continue: true

  - receiver: 'receiver_2'
    matchers:
      - project_name = "y"
    continue: true

receivers:
  - name: 'common_channel'
    slack_configs:
    - channel: 'channel-common'
      send_resolved: true

  - name: 'receiver_1'
    slack_configs:
    - channel: 'channel-1'
      send_resolved: true

  - name: 'receiver_2'
    slack_configs:
    - channel: 'channel-2'
      send_resolved: true
```

Comment: Have you considered implementing this within alert expression itself? Like rewriting query to check last 7 days, not just now, and adding `and on() day_of_week() == 1`?

Comment: Didn't tried this one. I think It will work. I didn't know about this function. Your reply led me finding more about the func ```day_of_week()```. Her is a good example: https://github.com/samber/awesome-prometheus-alerts/blob/master/sleep-peacefully.md. Thank you.

Comment: If now you can answer your question yourself - do it. (But remember to make it an actual answer, so it can help other users later)

Comment: But it partially solved. But using ```day_of_week() == 1``` will fire alert only Monday but whole day. I wanted ti fire alert once on Monday.

Comment: Then something like `and on() (day_of_week() == 1 and hour()=9)`